# how to connect to confluent kafka broker using kraft mode in AWS ec2

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running a single node cluster confluent kafka community edition 7.5.3 in kraft mode.

AWS ec2 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Downloaded using `curl -O https://packages.confluent.io/archive/7.5/confluent-community-7.5.3.tar.gz`

Have modified the `listeners` value in `broker.properties` under `etc/kafka/kraft/` dir.

**broker.properties**

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The role of this server. Setting this puts us in KRaft mode
process.roles=broker

# The node id associated with this instance's roles
node.id=2

# The connect string for the controller quorum
controller.quorum.voters=1@localhost:9093

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. If not configured, the host name will be equal to the value of
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(), with PLAINTEXT listener name, and port 9092.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

# Name of listener used for communication between brokers.
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT

# Listener name, hostname and port the broker will advertise to clients.
# If not set, it uses the value for "listeners".
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

# A comma-separated list of the names of the listeners used by the controller.
# This is required if running in KRaft mode. On a node with `process.roles=broker`, only the first listed listener will be used by the broker.
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
```

**controller.properties**

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The role of this server. Setting this puts us in KRaft mode
process.roles=controller

# The node id associated with this instance's roles
node.id=1

# The connect string for the controller quorum
controller.quorum.voters=1@localhost:9093

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on.
# Note that only the controller listeners are allowed here when `process.roles=controller`, and this listener should be consistent with `controller.quorum.voters` value.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=CONTROLLER://:9093

# A comma-separated list of the names of the listeners used by the controller.
# This is required if running in KRaft mode.
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
```

Steps performed to run the confluent kafka:

1. kafka-storage random-uuid
2. bin/kafka-storage format -t <generated_id> -c etc/kafka/kraft/controller.properties
3. bin/kafka-storage format -t <generated_id> -c etc/kafka/kraft/broker.properties
4. bin/kafka-server-start ./etc/kafka/kraft/controller.properties
5. bin/kafka-server-start ./etc/kafka/kraft/broker.properties

When I am trying to connect to the broker using public ip of ec2 machine. I am not able to connect to the broker. I am getting Timeout.

I have checked the security group,
[image]

I am able to do netcat also,

```
> nc -z <public_ip_of_ec2> 9092
Connection to <public_ip_of_ec2> port 9092 [tcp/XmlIpcRegSvc] succeeded!
```

Comment: Your question is about connection just to Kafka. Confluent Platform is what you downloaded, but it still is Apache Kafka... And you're not using Confluent Cloud. Please keep tag changes